# Sorting a list with multi-part items

Tags: bash, list, sorting

third try to understand what Im doing wrong.

Ive got a list like this:

```
array[0] = 1111 Here is much text
array[1] = 2222 Here is even more text
array[2] = 1111.1 Here is special text
```

Now I want to sort the list to have it like this:

```
1111 Here is much text
1111.1 Here is special text
2222 Here is even more text
```

Using

```
for j in ${array[@]}; do echo $j; done | sort -n
```

it seperates me every single part because of the spaces.

Using

```
for j in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$j"; done | sort -n
```

I get a sorted list like 1111 2222 1111.1

Answer (score 3):

```
array=(
    "1111 Here is much text" 
    "2222 Here is even more text" 
    "1111.1 Here is special text"
)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n
```

```
1111 Here is much text
1111.1 Here is special text
2222 Here is even more text
```

To save it:

```
sorted=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    sorted+=("$line")
done  < <( printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n )
printf "%s\n" "${sorted[@]}"
# same output as above
```

or

```
source <( echo 'sorted=('; printf '"%s"\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -n; echo ')' )
printf "%s\n" "${sorted[@]}"
```

---

Carriage returns in your file will mess you up. Consider file named "t" with dos-style line endings:

```
$ cat -e t
line1^M$
line2^M$
line3^M$
$ for n in {1..3} ; do array[n]="$(echo $n $(cat t))"; done
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"|od -c
0000000   1       l   i   n   e   1  \r       l   i   n   e   2  \r    
0000020   l   i   n   e   3  \r  \n   2       l   i   n   e   1  \r    
0000040   l   i   n   e   2  \r       l   i   n   e   3  \r  \n   3    
0000060   l   i   n   e   1  \r       l   i   n   e   2  \r       l   i
0000100   n   e   3  \r  \n
0000105
$ printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
 line31
 line31
 line31
```

Clearly this is going to mess up anything you feed with this input. Fix the carriage returns.

Comment: Nice, if I could 1UP again, I would

Comment: funny thing: the first 2 versions dont work. the last one sorts everything fine but partly, every word from the text is seperated ...

Comment: did you retype or cut-and-paste? It is crucial to quote the variables exactly as shown

Comment: I have no idea. You'll have to show us what you're doing and what you see. Are you sure that what's in your array is what you think is in your array?

Comment: I fill the array with array[IDX]="$(echo $NUMMER $(cat tmp4.txt))";

Comment: You must have strange characters in your data. Try `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | od -c` and look for things like `\r`

Comment: and what am I doing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your locale is set in such a way that the `.` is interpreted as a thousands separator, rather than a decimal point, and the numeric values are sorted accordingly (1111.1 is interpreteted as 11111, e.g. with `LC_ALL=de_DE`). Use

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

before you execute `sort` (and, of course, use proper quoting, as in glenn's and fedorqui's answers).